# Fetching data from mySql database for php user session

Tags: php, mysql

I'm relatively new to PHP and mySQL, and I'm trying to create user sessions with fields from a mySQL database.

The way I've set it up means that I am getting a session with the two fields entered into the login form (username and password) by checking these against the database, but I cannot retrieve any other data from the database and add it to the session.

How can I retrieve other data from the database and add this to the new session?

```
<?php
require('db.php');
session_start();

// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    // removes backslashes
    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
    //escapes special characters in a string
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
        //This one works
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        //This one doesn't
        $_SESSION['email'] = $rows ['email'];

        // Redirect user to index.php 
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        echo "<div class='form'>
        <p>Username/password is incorrect.</p>
        <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
}else{
}
?>
```

Comment: Just using a hash function such as MD5 is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$rows` is  counter variable (having count of number of records) there that's why not working.

Do like below:-

```
....previous code as it is
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //fetch record
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        header("Location: index.php");
    }...rest code as it is
```

Note:-

1.Don't use `md5` password encryption, use `password hashing` technique.

2.Use `prepared statements` of `mysqli_*` to prevent your code from ***SQL Injection***

Comment: Thanks! That's worked for me.

I'll look into the password encryption and prepared statements, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @PhillipMitchell  GLAD TO HELP YOU :)